How to copy file path to clipboard?
Suppose I have a file selected in Files. How can I copy it's full file path to the clipboard? hitting <CTRL>+L followed by <CTRL>+C (or <CTRL>+X) just copies the path of the parent directory to the clipboard. How to get the full path copied to clipboard?
I am not looking for drag-and-drop functionality (e.g., I already know I can drag the file to, say the terminal app, to paste it's path there).

A quick check in my 22.04.5 LTS shows that it is enough with ctrl+c when a file is selected in Files. I verified by pasting in a terminal window. I am surprised that you have problems in 24.04.1 LTS.

and Ctrl+c works with 24.04.1 too

A check in a live instance of 24.04.1 LTS (booted from USB) shows the same result. Simply use ctrl+c to copy the whole file path (full directory path and file name) to clipboard. So I can verify the statement of graham.

If you copy the file with right click and then paste on a text field it will paste the whole path to that file as text.

OH! Heck yeah. Go... uh... mime types!

@Lexible Glad I could help :)


Select a FILE, then CTRL+C (in GUI, "Files", Nautilus). Paste anywhere and you will get the full file path.

... to be complete:

Drop a file (icon) in Terminal, i.e. at the Bash prompt and you'll see the file+path.

Select any text, a filename and or path in the Terminal, CTRL+SHIFT+C copies it, SHIFT+CTRL+V to paste in the terminal, CTRL+V everywhere else.

Type this in Terminal (Hit Enter after each line) and you will have a new clipb command to use there:


sudo apt install xclip
cd 
mkdir bin
cat >bin/clipb <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
# Linux version
# Use this script to pipe in/out of the clipboard
#
# Usage: someapp | clipboard     # Pipe someapp's output into clipboard
#        clipboard | someapp     # Pipe clipboard's content into someapp
#
    
if command -v xclip 1>/dev/null; then
    if [[ -p /dev/stdin ]] ; then
        # stdin is a pipe
        # stdin -> clipboard
        xclip -i -selection clipboard
    else
        # stdin is not a pipe
        # clipboard -> stdout
        xclip -o -selection clipboard
    fi
else
    echo "Remember to install xclip"
fi
EOF
chmod 755 bin/clipb
echo >>.bash_aliases "export PATH=\$HOME/bin:\$PATH"

e.g.
$ echo hello | clipb will have you paste hello anywhere with CTRL+V / SHIFT+CTRL+V (in a terminal).

@kos, thanks!!  I forgot to add <<EOF and a EOF line! AND I've been hunting for the syntax highlighting...

No problem :) maybe you'll be interested in this (the list is probably outdated, I think mods have the power to access the actual list, however the general rule is that if a language is supported and a tag with the name of the language exists, you may just use the language's name, such as I did with bash, oherwise you can prepend lang- and have it work anyways, e.g. lang-console)

I have that actual posting marked (saved) as "Reference" - but never got it to work, following the examples. :-}  obviously I didn't try the last example!

I changed it removing the comments, perhaps those were confusing, hopefully it's a bit more clear now

I saw this again in the HNQ, reading it again: why are you adding the PATH export to ~/.bash_aliases? It doesn't appear to be making much sense, that's not what ~/.bash_aliases is for, personally I'd suggest manually putting the export in ~/.bashrc (also to avoid overriding PATH with a $HOME/bin path that has more precedence than something the user might have set in PATH already)

.bashrc is provided in the installation, .bash_aliases is not; the choice is to keep updates of .bashrc "open" not affected by user additions. For $PATH; anything in there named the same as something existing SHOULD have higher precedence, simply because you have made that active and actual choice by naming it the same.

I don't agree that ~/.bashrc should be kept clean from user additions; while it's true that some (automatic) additions might be made to it, the rationale behind the file is exactly to have a place to store user additions. By putting stuff in ~/.bash_aliases I think you're changing a (in my opinion) non-existing problem to... an actual problem / inconsistency where something else is stored where it's not supposed to.

Not every distribution sources ~/.bash_aliases, in fact I'm pretty sure e.g. OpenSUSE doesn't. What are users supposed to do on those distros if they can't neither use ~/.bash_aliases nor change ~/.bashrc? :) The custom is to put additions in ~/.bashrc, using ~/.bash_aliases is kind of a "dirty hack" that only works on certain distributions. I personally wouldn't do that but hey, I'm not claiming it wouldn't work. Just that it doesn't make too much sense overall. And it's just my opinion anyways :)

We're in "Ask Ubuntu" so I don't claim to be distro agnostic here ;-) - I got a big bump in Bash knowledge through the Bash guides at tldp.org a good while back. And been practicing what i remember from then, may be 'wrong' in some sense - but with real practical 'in use locally' experience on top of it. So; works fine for me, on Ubuntu. Oh; that script above is the "in use" section of the my actual clipb which actually contains "saved code" dated in 2013 ;-)

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749544/pipe-to-from-the-clipboard-in-a-bash-script for more on the clipboard topic.

Sure, I don't claim you should've been distro-agnostic; I was just backing up my point that it's customary to just put stuff in ~/.bashrc. Yeah, your method surely will still work, it wasn't my point :)
